# Way for VBA script to find last CSV file in download folder?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible for a VBA macro to loop through files in the download folder in order to import the last (most recent) CSV ?

ChatGPT has suggested the following.

```
Sub ImportLastCSVFile()    
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strRawPath As String

    ' Replace with the correct download directory
    strRawPath = "C:\Users\AlexandreBrandt\Downloads\"
    strPath = strRawPath & "*.csv"
    strFile = Dir(strPath, vbNormal)

    ' Find the last CSV file
    While Len(strFile) <> 0
        If FileDateTime(strRawPath & strFile) > FileDateTime(strRawPath & strPath) Then
            strPath = strFile
        End If
        strFile = Dir() ' Get next file
    Wend

    ' Set the workbook and worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Import")
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
```

The VBE debugger is not accepting
`If FileDateTime(strRawPath & strFile) > FileDateTime(strRawPath & strPath) Then`

Is there a better way to write the loop through the files?

Comment: `strRawPath & strPath` makes no sense, it contains the path twice. What do you want to compare to? If you need the last file by date, you would have to store the date and check each file against the stored date.

Comment: Hey Paul.
In fact it needs to compare against todays date. Today's date and time would be the most resent.

Comment: This is way easier using Data, Get Data, From File, From Folder. Filter the filelist the correct path (by default PQ looks in all sub-folders too), filter for CSV extension, sort Descending on file date and then "Keep first row only" and expand the data. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Import the Latest CSV File

```vb
Sub ImportLatestCSVFile()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Users\AlexandreBrandt\Downloads\"
    Const SRC_FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.csv"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Import"
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Attempt to store the first file name in a variable ('CurrentFileName').
    
    Dim DirPath As String: DirPath = SRC_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH & SRC_FILE_PATTERN
    
    Dim CurrentFileName As String: CurrentFileName = Dir(DirPath)
    
    If Len(CurrentFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Store the path of the latest file in a variable ('LatestFilePath').
    
    ' Declare additional variables used in the loop.
    Dim CurrentFilePath As String, LatestFilePath As String
    Dim CurrentDateTime As Date, LatestDateTime As Date
    
    ' Loop through all the files applying the logic...
    Do While Len(CurrentFileName) > 0
        CurrentFilePath = SRC_ROOT_FOLDER_PATH & CurrentFileName
        CurrentDateTime = FileDateTime(CurrentFilePath)
        If CurrentDateTime >= LatestDateTime Then ' greater than or equal to max
            LatestDateTime = CurrentDateTime
            LatestFilePath = CurrentFilePath
        'Else ' less than max; do nothing
        End If
        CurrentFileName = Dir ' next file
    Loop

    ' Attempt to delete the destination worksheet ('dws').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not dws Is Nothing Then ' the worksheet exists
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
            dws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Else ' the worksheet doesn't exist; do nothing
    End If

    ' Continue, e.g.:
    
'    ' Copy the one and only worksheet in the source file ('.csv')
'    ' as the last sheet in the destination workbook.
'
'    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(LatestFilePath)
'    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(1)
'
'    sws.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count) ' copy as last sheet
'    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' close without saving changes
'
'    ' Reference and rename the destination worksheet and save
'    ' the destination workbook.
'
'    Set dws = dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
'    dws.Name = DST_SHEET_NAME
'    'dwb.Save
'    
'    ' Inform.
'    
'    MsgBox "Latest file imported.", vbInformation        

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello there
Thanks for the suggestion here.

I'm wondering why would their be a section to delete the destination worksheet.
Is this to delete it or rather to prevent it be overwritten with the the new CSV import?

Comment: The idea is that if you want the imported worksheet to be called `Import` but another (previously imported?) worksheet is already named `Import`, then you want to delete the existing worksheet and copy the new worksheet instead. Your posted code deletes a worksheet at the bottom. If that's not the functionality you're looking for, add more detail to your post.

Comment: Hey, ok I see!
Yes I wanted to name it as `Import` because the excel tabs are limited in their names length and so using the imported CSV full name could lead to issues.

I imagine that Excel does truncate the name when the user imports via the Data -> From Text/CSV but that would be something that the VBA would need to specify.

Answer (score 1):

It's close.. Replace the initial chunk of code (down to Wend) with:

```
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strLatestFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strRawPath As String

' Replace with the correct download directory
strRawPath = "C:\Users\AlexandreBrandt\Downloads\"
strPath = strRawPath & "*.csv"
strFile = Dir(strPath, vbNormal)
strLatestFile = strFile

' Find the last CSV file
While Len(strFile) <> 0
    If FileDateTime(strRawPath & strFile) > FileDateTime(strRawPath & strLatestFile) Then
        strLatestFile = strFile
        Debug.Print "Latest file set to : " & strFile
    End If
    strFile = Dir() ' Get next file
Wend
strFile = strLatestFile
```

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for the suggestion.

So this codes runs smooth but nothing actually happens. 
When going in break mode, I see the VBA is looping indefinitely here

`' Find the last CSV file
    While Len(strFile) <> 0
        If FileDateTime(strRawPath & strFile) > FileDateTime(strRawPath & strLatestFile) Then
            strLatestFile = strFile
        End If
        strFile = Dir() ' Get next file
    Wend`
So it does not get out of that. I guess its not finding the file according to those parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure how that gets *stuck* in a loop. It works fine on my machine, reading every CSV file and storing the latest in `strFile`.  You just need to (presumably) add some code to open it?

Comment: Hello. Ah, I see how this is working.
Its looping though every CSV in the downloads folder.
But will only store one value in strFile?

Is there a way in the VBE to what values has been stored into the variables to see if this is getting stored correctly.

The files do not have any passwords, they can be opened.

Comment: You can use the Watch Window, drag a variable into it from the code. Or you can `Debug.Print strFile` in the code to see it output to your Immediate Window during runtime. I've added a `Debug.Print` to the code as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to store in a variable the latest date and in another variable the latest file. Whenever you find a newer file, just override them:

```
    strFile = Dir(strPath, vbNormal)
    Dim strLatestFile As String = ""
    Dim currentDate As DateTime
    Dim latestDate As DateTime

    ' Find the last CSV file
    While Len(strFile) <> 0
        If strLatestFile.Equals("") Then
            strLatestFile = strFile
            currentDate =  = FileDateTime(strRawPath & strLatestFile)
            latestDate = currentDate
        End If
        If currentDate > latestDate Then
            strLatestFile = strFile
            latestDate = currentDate
        End If
        strFile = Dir() ' Get next file
        currentDate = FileDateTime(strRawPath & strFile)
    Wend
```

Now, you can use `strLatestFile` however you please.